# Resetting <f:selectItems/>

Tags: jsf

In my JSF application I have h:selectOneMenu and h:selectOneListBox tags that work perfectly correctly, but I do not know how to reset them back to the first entry, which is the default.

One example of my xhtml code is as follows:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="physmenu" value="#{index.physics}" style="height:25px; width:180px;">   
    <f:selectItems value="#{index.physicsMap}"/>   
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

and part of the corresponding bean is:

```
@ManagedBean(name="index")   
@SessionScoped  
public class MyIndexBean implements Serializable {   
    // Other private variables   
    private String itemValue;   
    private String itemLabel;   
    private String physics;   

    Map<String,String> physicsMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();

    private void initPhysics() {   
        // Loop through data read from an input file   
        // Get itemValue and itemLabel for each line of input read   

        physicsMap.put(itemLabel, itemValue); // Store these in physicsMap each time in the loop   

        // Other code   

        }    
    }   

    public Map<String,String> getPhysicsMap() {   
        return physicsMap;   
    }   

    // ----- Getter and setter for physics for the index page -----   

    public String getPhysics() {   
        return physics;   
    }   

    public void setPhysics(String physics) {   
        this.physics = physics;   
    }   

    public void resetPhysics(ActionEvent event) {   
        physicsMap.clear();   
    }   
}
```

Likewise in a similar way for h:selectOneListBox, and in a couple of places in my Java code I have an array of objects that I created rather than a LinkedHashMap.

As I read in data from a file, I want to keep it in memory and somehow reset the pointer that JSF uses to specify which is the selected item, but I don't know how to access that pointer.  The ActionEvent method at the end just clears the Map, so is of little use.

When a page is first visited the first menu item is displayed, exactly as I want, but if it is changed then the submit button is clicked, then when I revisit the page the new selected value is still displayed and I cannot see how to reset it to the first menu item.  How does JSF keep track of the index pointing to the selected value in the Map displayed on the page, and how do I reset it, or if I so wish, set it to another value programmatically?

This is an issue that has bugged me for some time, and I cannot find a solution.  Many thanks for any help

Comment: First check code for initPhysics, I think you forgot to copy something. Second your bean is session scoped, it stays in memory for whole user session. Try to use view scoped bean instead.

Answer (score 2):

The selected value is the `#{index.physics}`. You need to make it `null`.

An alternative is to just put the bean in request or view scope. I don't believe that the session scope is the right scope for the purpose. See also [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941)

Comment: Many thanks, but in the end I found that by using FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove("index"); works instead, as I want to keep my beans session scoped.

Comment: That's definitely bad design. Your webapp would behave weird when the enduser has the same page opened in multiple browser tabs/windows. Use the view scope instead. See also the in the answer mentioned link.